# Android 5.0.2 Lollipop- Moto G 1st Gen Wifi Hotspot issue

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I am unable to browse internet in laptop using Wifi Hotspot of my Moto G after it got updated to Lollypop. Any one has a solution?

Comment: Below worked for me... Hope it works for you too...Go To  Settings -> More -> Cellular networks -> Access Point Names and then on right hand side top click on three vertical dots and select "Reset to default" .... This works .....

Answer (score 2):

Following solution worked for OP as mentioned [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/97856/android-5-0-2-lollipop-moto-g-1st-gen-wifi-hotspot-issue#comment123055_97856):

> Go To Settings → More → Cellular networks → Access Point Names → at the top on the right side, click on three vertical dots and select "Reset to default".